# incorrect error in VS Code using ts-standard in a mono-repo

Tags: visual-studio-code, ts-standard

I have several tsconfigs in my project (one for server-side code, and another for client-side). When I lint using `ts-standard`, I receive no errors (as expected). To lint from the terminal:

```bash
ts-standard assets/scripts/ --project ./assets/scripts/tsconfig.json & ts-standard src/ --project ./src/tsconfig.json
```

No issue there. However, in my editor (VS Code), the JavaScript Standard Style extension shows the following two problems at the top of the file (i.e. at the first `import` statement):

> This rule requires the `strictNullChecks` compiler option to be turned on to function correctly. (@typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing) `ts-standard(@typescript-eslint/prefer-nullish-coalescing)`

> This rule requires the `strictNullChecks` compiler option to be turned on to function correctly. (@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions) `ts-standard(@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions)`

### What I have tried

I have searched on DuckDuckGo and asked ChatGPT and Copilot, but found no solution. It works fine with just one tsconfig, but having two seems to be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by installing ESLint along a few other packages:

```bash
bun i -D eslint eslint-config-standard-with-typescript @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-n eslint-plugin-promise
```

Then configuring ESLint in `package.json`:

```json
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "standard-with-typescript",
  ],
  "ignorePatterns": [
    "*.d.ts"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "project": [
      "assets/scripts/tsconfig.json",
      "src/tsconfig.json"
    ]
  },
  "plugins": [
    "@typescript-eslint"
  ]
}
```

Now, when using the ESLint extension for VS Code, the reported problems are consistent between command-line and in the editor.